# aws lambda and promise-mysql

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-mysql

i've encountered an issue using the promise-mysql library within aws lambda.

this is for upgrade the lambda functions from node 4.3 to node 10.x   and is using "promise-mysql": "^4.1.0"

the code does something like this...

```
mysql.createConnection({
    host : RdsHost,
    user : RdsUser,
    password : RdsPassword,
    database : RdsDatabase
}).then((conn) => {
    connection = conn;                      // defined earlier
    return connection;
})
.then(() => {
    var ffff = new FFFF(connection);        // passes in connection
    return ffff.getRows();                  // runs query via connection
})
.then((rows) => {
    ...
})
.then(() => {
    var pppp = new PPPP(connection);        // passes in connection
    return pppp.getRows();                  // runs query via connection
})
.then((rows) => {
    xxxx = rows;
})
.then(() => {
    if(connection) connection.end();        // <- if timeout failure does NOT fall over into .catch
    console.log('Result is ', xxxx);
    return context.succeed(xxxx);
})
.catch(function(err){
    if(connection) connection.end();
    console.log(err);
    return context.fail(new Error(configuration.ApiGatewayErrorRegex + 'Could not process the query' + err));
});
```

there is a keybounce issue on the screen which i will eventually but cannot right now.

the lambda runs and gets a result but when the .end() is called it returns the following errors:

```
'ERROR Unhandled Promise Rejection'
'Error: Quit inactivity timeout'
'PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT'
```

this was happening in previous version of the code (node4.3) but was not flooding the monitoring with errors and rds alerts.

in order to reduce the errors and rds alerts i've had to do something like the following...

```
.then(() => {
    if(connection)  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        connection.end( err => {
            if ( err ) return reject( err );
            resolve();
        }).then(() => {
            console.log('Result is (e):', xxxx);
            return context.succeed(xxxx);
        });
    });
    //fall-through
    console.log('Result is:', xxxx);
    return context.succeed(xxxx);
})
.catch(function(err){
    if(connection)  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        connection.end( err => {
            if ( err ) return reject( err );
            resolve();
        }).then(() => {
            console.log(err);
            return context.fail(new Error(configuration.ApiGatewayErrorRegex + 'Could not process the query' + err));
        });
    });
    //fall-through
    console.log(err);
    return context.fail(new Error(configuration.ApiGatewayErrorRegex + 'Could not process the query' + err));
});
```

which seems unsatisfactory considering i would have thought the .catch() would have managed this condition.
[ed: further testing shows it makes virtually no difference anyway].

part of the issue is that the code needs to return a context.succeed or context.failure   and so the promise stuff has become extremely verbose to accommodate this.

i have tried .destroy() instead of .end() and this did work as .destroy() is not returning a promise. however i wanted to keep the code as close to the original version as possible.

[ed] i have also tried (suggested elsewhere) doing
connection.end(function(err){})
or similar but this also did not work.

has anyone had similar issues and if so did you have a better work around?

Answer (score 0):

worked it out eventually. the "wrap everything in a promise" approach didn't work.

```
.then(() => {
    if(connection) connection.end();     <----
    console.log('Result is ', xxxx);
    return context.succeed(xxxx);
})
```

this was the bit causing the issue. the connection.end() throwing the error due to timing out.

what i used to fix it was...

```
if(connection)  connection.end().catch(function(e){console.log('connection.end: '+e)});
```

i was under the impression that chaining the connection create and thens and putting a catch on the end was enough to handle errors but apparently not.